# When I tried to compile Bazel 0.1.0 with protoc 3.0.0 alpha 3 and jdk 1.8 on Jetson TK1, I met this JNI link error

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-native-interface, bazel, protobuf-c

When I tried to compile Bazel 0.1.0 with protoc 3.0.0 alpha 3 and jdk 1.8 on Jetson TK1, I met this JNI link error in Building Bazel tools.
    INFO: Blaze version info: Build label: head (@125b349)
    Build target: bazel-out/local_linux-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/bazel-main_deploy.jar
    Build time: Fri Feb 24 08:29:59 2017 (1487924999)
    Build timestamp: 1487924999
    Build timestamp as int: 1487924999
    Feb 24, 2017 9:08:10 AM com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime main
    INFO: Starting Blaze server with args [--max_idle_secs, 10800, --install_base=/home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/install/2dac0f619e9cc270a8fcbda27d4228ba, --install_md5=2dac0f619e9cc270a8fcbda27d4228ba, --output_base=/home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/9a43f1fcce27c7feee2a9f965aa85b05, --workspace_directory=/home/ubuntu/Downloads/bazel, --nofatal_event_bus_exceptions, --option_sources=blazerc:]
    JNI initialization failed: /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/install/2dac0f619e9cc270a8fcbda27d4228ba/_embedded_binaries/libunix.so: /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/install/2dac0f619e9cc270a8fcbda27d4228ba/_embedded_binaries/libunix.so: unexpected reloc type 0x03.  Possibly your installation has been corrupted; if this problem persists, try 'rm -fr /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/install/2dac0f619e9cc270a8fcbda27d4228ba'.
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/install/2dac0f619e9cc270a8fcbda27d4228ba/_embedded_binaries/libunix.so: /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/install/2dac0f619e9cc270a8fcbda27d4228ba/_embedded_binaries/libunix.so: unexpected reloc type 0x03
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.UnixJniLoader.loadJni(UnixJniLoader.java:25)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.unix.ProcessUtils.(ProcessUtils.java:27)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.ProcessUtils$1.getpid(ProcessUtils.java:53)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.ProcessUtils.getpid(ProcessUtils.java:77)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.OsUtils.forceJNI(OsUtils.java:56)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.OsUtils.maybeForceJNI(OsUtils.java:43)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.newRuntime(BlazeRuntime.java:1437)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.createBlazeRPCServer(BlazeRuntime.java:1328)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.serverMain(BlazeRuntime.java:1301)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.main(BlazeRuntime.java:1097)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.bazel.BazelMain.main(BazelMain.java:56)
    Feb 24, 2017 9:08:10 AM com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BugReport printThrowableTo
    SEVERE: Blaze crashed
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/install/2dac0f619e9cc270a8fcbda27d4228ba/_embedded_binaries/libunix.so: /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/install/2dac0f619e9cc270a8fcbda27d4228ba/_embedded_binaries/libunix.so: unexpected reloc type 0x03
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.UnixJniLoader.loadJni(UnixJniLoader.java:25)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.unix.ProcessUtils.(ProcessUtils.java:27)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.ProcessUtils$1.getpid(ProcessUtils.java:53)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.ProcessUtils.getpid(ProcessUtils.java:77)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.OsUtils.forceJNI(OsUtils.java:56)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.OsUtils.maybeForceJNI(OsUtils.java:43)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.newRuntime(BlazeRuntime.java:1437)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.createBlazeRPCServer(BlazeRuntime.java:1328)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.serverMain(BlazeRuntime.java:1301)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.main(BlazeRuntime.java:1097)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.bazel.BazelMain.main(BazelMain.java:56)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bazel 0.1.0 is an old release, the latest is 0.4.4.

Did you try following the [Compiling from Source](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/install.html#compiling-from-source) instructions?

Comment: I retry to follow the instruction to install bazel and successfully install bazel 0.1.0. THX !!